# MySQLI- Allow the Forward Slash to be Used With Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, escaping

I have a MySQL field ("*imagelocation*") that contains the relative pathname to an image. Essentially the construct: "*DirectoryName/ImageName.png*" The "***/***" is causing a problem. I get the error message: "*Unknown column 'Analog' in 'field list'*" (Analog is the name of the directory.)

Prior to building the pathname, the following code is executed to return only a "*clean*" image name.

```
$imagelocation=trim(SanitizeString($_FILES['imagevar']['name']));
```

The pathname is built with the following code:

```
$imagelocation=trim($magazinedirectory . "/" . $imagelocation);
```

The query to be executed:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tblIssueList(IssueDate,MagazineNUM,CoverArtistNUM,ImageLocation)" .
        " VALUES({$issuedate},{$magazineidnum},{$artistidnum},{$imagelocation})";
```

The query works when "*imagelocation*" is removed. The query also works with "*imagelocation*" when the ***"/"*** is removed.

How can the relative pathname be stored in the field "*imagelocation*"?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and if you were using proper SAFE query construction techniques, would never have had this problem in the first place. As written, you are telling the DB to do DIVISION: `INSERT ... VALUES(bar/baz/qux)` is "bar divided by baz divided by qux", and not a path

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks for the thought. I am still learning MySQLi, its a slow-go, Learning PHP,MYSQL & Javascript by Nixon covers the use prepared statements and placeholders to improve security. This database is currently on a home LAN. No internet access. When I get over the "simple" problems, such as my current post; I will have time to incorporate more advanced features.

Comment: @SteveR. Honestly, you are better off not learning it wrong to begin with.  Any book, blog, or tutorial that tells you it's *ever* okay to build queries with string concatenation instead of placeholders and prepared statements should, almost certainly, be summarily dismissed as a qualified resource.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Thanks. The book **recommends** using prepared statements with placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to quote your values in the INSERT command MySQL, will add single words for strings, and without special characters, if you add quotes, it treats all the value as an string:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tblIssueList(IssueDate,MagazineNUM,CoverArtistNUM,ImageLocation)" .
    " VALUES('{$issuedate}','{$magazineidnum}','{$artistidnum}','{$imagelocation}')";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. [Prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)  are the way to go here.

Comment: @Ramy Deeb: Worked!  Thank-you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I'm still at the bottom of the learning curve. I was unaware of the solution of adding quotes provided by Ramy. I am aware of prepared statements, but have yet to incorporate it. My database is on a home LAN, not accessible through the internet. Of course that is not an excuse not to incorporate better approaches. As I get more proficient, I will incorporate enhanced code. For now the emphasis is getting the database working even at the rudimentary level.